# Does a non-static variable in a non-static method correspond to that of the object?

Tags: java, oop, static

Please see below, where I have created an object for the class, and used the method nonstaticMethod to change the value of a non-static integer variable. I'm able to do this without the use of 'this' keyword?

Is nonstaticVariable inside nonstaticMethod same as this.nonstaticVariable ?

```
package lastcommon;

public class Check {

    int nonstaticVariable = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Check obCheck = new Check();

        obCheck.nonstaticMethod();
    }

    void nonstaticMethod()
    {
        nonstaticVariable = 200;
        System.out.println(nonstaticVariable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most people refer to "non-static" variables/methods as "instance" variables/methods. The only time you need to explicitly specify `this` is when a variable within the method has the same name as the instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `nonstaticVariable = 200;` **is** short for `this.nonstaticVariable = 200;` you can see this by printing it after the method call like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Check obCheck = new Check();
    obCheck.nonstaticMethod();

    System.out.println(obCheck.nonstaticVariable);
}
```

Comment: ... and instance variables would be useless if this wasn't the case.